# How to get rkhunter to skip "[Press <ENTER> to continue]"

Tags: configuration, rkhunter

Every time that I scan my machine with `rkhunter` using the following command:

```
sudo rkhunter --checkall
```

After it has finished with a certain type of check it asks me:

```
[Press <ENTER> to continue]
```

And this has become rather annoying and I keep forgetting that I have run it, so hours later I realise that it has been sitting on that prompt all this time. It is also rather annoying that I have to sit staring at it the whole time while it is doing the scan so that I can press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to allow it to continue.

So really that is my question, is there any way in which I can get it not to prompt me to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> but just to get on with the scan so that all I have to do is to run it by executing the initial command and then come back later to check the results?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
rkhunter:
  Installed: 1.4.0-3
  Candidate: 1.4.0-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.0-3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script)?

Comment: @A.B.: And how exactly would I achieve this with what I have? As that is for writing a script is it not? And I am not writing a script. So would I have to write a script like this and run it with `rkhunter`, or would I have to edit the source code of `rkhunter`? Or would there be some other means by which it could be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`man rkhunter`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rkhunter.8):

```
--sk, --skip-keypress
      When the --check command option is used, after certain  sections
      of  tests,  the user will be prompted to press the return key in
      order to  continue.  This  option  disables  that  feature,  and
      rkhunter will run until all the tests have completed.
      If  this  option has not been given, and the user is prompted to
      press the return key, a  single  's'  character,  in  upper-  or
      lowercase,  may  be  given  followed by the return key. rkhunter
      will then continue the tests without prompting  the  user  again
      (as if this option had been given).
```

Comment: Ok, this is obviously the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
echo | sudo rkhunter --checkall
```

Comment: I think you can use the `yes` command to do this for repeated checks: `yes $'\n' | sudo rkhunter --checkall`.

Comment: Why, `echo | sudo rkhunter --checkall` works fine.

Comment: Interesting. I'd expected `rkhunter` to skip subsequent checks if it got EOF.

Comment: I also suspected, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `rkhunter` with `cronjob`, you can use the script

```
/usr/bin/rkhunter -c -sk
```

Tested by me on my Centos 7.